# Inline vf page to Related Section

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, case

Is there any way to put inline visual force page to related list section of case object?As per my understanding we can create new section above the related lists and we can put over there..but i wanted to know is there any other way to put vf page to related list section??

Answer (score 1):

You could override the View of the object on which you want to embed your visualforce page by another visualforce page.

In this new page you can display your standard layout with `<apex:detail>` and include the related page with `<apex:include>`. Now the positioning is either above or below. Possibly below is already good enough because it would be practically the last related list.

If you have some JavaScript and DOM skills with jquery it shouldn't be too hard to move your embedded page practically everwhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

Inline Visualforce pages, as of now, cannot be embedded in any part of the page layout but in the detail section in the standard web UI.

In the mobile Salesforce1 UI, however, you can embed a mobile card Visualforce page, which appears on the related list view of the record carousel.